# Count not working on api.list_direct_messages (Tweepy)

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm trying to make a function to delete the last 5 DMs sent in a project I'm working on, but I can only get all DMs sent which reaches the rate limit, therefore forcing Tweepy to wait over 30 seconds. Code:

```py
import tweepy

CONSUMER_KEY = 'private'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'private'
ACCESS_KEY = 'private'
ACCESS_SECRET = 'private'
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

dms = api.list_direct_messages(5)
print(len(dms))
for i in range(len(dms)):
    api.destroy_direct_message(dms[i]._json['id'])
```

When I run it, `print(len(dms))`
prints 0, showing that it didn't get the list at all.

Answer (score 0):

The `count` parameter for the [GET direct_messages/events/list](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/direct-messages/sending-and-receiving/api-reference/list-events) Twitter API endpoint that [`API.list_direct_messages`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v3.10.0/api.html#API.list_direct_messages) uses is the "max number of events to be returned".
It is not guaranteed to return that many.

You should use `Cursor` instead, to iterate over 5 direct messages.

Also, you can access the `id` directly as an attribute of `DirectMessage` objects.